# unable to set labelPosition in commandbar and appbarbuttons

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am writing a **UWP** app. I want to use **Icons and labels** in the app. So I created a `CommandBar` and put `AppBarButton` inside it. But the problem is that there is not `DefaultLabelPosition` property of `CommandBar` is available. Neither `LabelPosition` property of `AppBarButton` is available. Then I tried putting `AppBarButton` inside `StackPanel` and `Grid`. But `AppBarButton` still place `Label` below the `Icon`. I want to place the `Label` on right side of `Icon`. How to place `Label` in the right side of the `Icon`?. I searched the Internet in general and stackoverflow but didn't get any answer. I am not giving any code because this simply doesn't work in new project with just a single `CommandBar`. **MSDN** documentation have reference to the `DefautltLabelPositon` Property but `Intellisence` doesn't have that.I would prefer to use `AppBarButtons` inside `Grid` or `StackPanel` instead of `CommandBar`. I am working on `Visual studio 2015 update 2` with default `Min Version` and `Target Version`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that article too actually. I didn't gave it much of a tought until now. It really does not seem to have that property as you say. However I am able to reposition this lable. Here is a sample from my project:

```
<CommandBar>
    <AppBarToggleButton>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Add" />
            <TextBlock Text="Add" />
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBarToggleButton>
    <AppBarToggleButton Icon="RepeatAll" Label="Repeat" />
</CommandBar>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this is the workaround i applied at last. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A little late but you'll need Windows 10 Version 1607 (build 14393) for `DefaultLabelPosition` property.